# What's the need of using MPI pinning

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Can someone explain whats MPI pinning and why is it needed ?

Description from our cluster says this: but I dint understood much

mpirun -npernode 2 -pin 0_1_2_3 is your choice if you would like to test 1 OpenMP thread per MPI process and 4 MPI processes in total per node. Adding the LD_PRELOAD from above however decreases performance a lot. This is currently under investigation.

Comment: Pinning means to control exactly which MPI rank with how many OpenMP threads goes to which node (and maybe (virtual) CPU) in your cluster. The idea behind this is that OpenMP works only inside a node and that two MPI ranks living on the same node can communicate much faster than two living on distinct nodes. If you do not use OpenMP and there is enough RAM on the nodes to hold one MPI process per CPU then you probably do not need pinning at all.

Comment: Thats a nice explanaition. Thank you.